# Lightning component auto refresh to view the case record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-components

In Detail-record page, where you can see (activityTracking  page and related list) and on header of the page  there is new case button to create a new case record.

I have an activityTracking  page(lightning component) that display a Child object activity (Tracking of record page)details. Whenever detail page is opened, it automatically retrieve the record ID of that detail page and display those records(Activity) in activity component.

Instead of doing manual refresh, I want it to auto refresh the activityTracking page(lightning component) to view the case record by using NEW CASE button.

ActivityTrackingPage is a lightning component, where I need to write a code for auto refresh process.

Need suggestion please....

Comment: What does the button do? Is it a standard button or a Lightning component?

Comment: I would say get rid of the standard button and add a button to your lightning component. That way the lightning component can re-render itself once the case is created.

Comment: We can't remove the standard button as it is not on its own. there are some other buttons included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable route I see here, if the process for creating a Case is not under your control, is for your Lightning component to embed the [`<lightning:empApi>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) event streaming service.

You can then either

1. use the Streaming API to subscribe to notifications about record creation events or
2. write an Apex trigger that implements custom logic on the creation of your Support Case records to fire a Platform Event, to which the `empApi` component subscribes.

Your JavaScript callback from the empApi component can then take action to refresh your activity view upon receipt of one of those events.

The only other feasible solutions I see are:

1. Polling. I wouldn't recommend it.
2. If and only if the data model permits - that is, if Support Case is a child object in a master-detail relationship - you could create a Roll-Up Summary Field and then use [`<force:recordData>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification) to watch for change events in the *parent object's* roll up field, representing creation events for the child object. I think it's unlikely that that applies here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

I am aware of steaming Api and platform event concept, do you have any reference doc for solve this,

Comment: @Ajay There is no documentation that I am aware of that specifically covers this problem. You would need to do some work that combines different Salesforce features, including events and Lightning client-side controller work.

Comment: If you see the Lightning Experience roadmap , what you want is called [Live Record](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm) . Salesforce has not set any timelines for it

Comment: @DavidReed I have tried with some code and its working too but initially when i tried to insert the record its throwing error but after closed that error and tried second time, its working. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264754/lightning-empapi-error?noredirect=1#comment400737_264754 please check for more info

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, I did with lightning empApi , please have a look this link and let me know any correction if needed please https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264754/lightning-empapi-error?noredirect=1#comment400737_264754

Comment: @DavidReed, I have tried using 2 options and its wok well too. but sometimes i find component behavior is throwing error and sometime its working well quiet confusing too.
Could you explain me bit more about how  the flow is working please and please how to write for error handle code.

Comment: @DavidReed I am working with your suggestion. my question is do we must to include unsubscribe method in js controller . So far My component is working as we expected but very rare cases, record is not updating. that's why i am aware of whether we need to use unsubscribe method is must to include into the js controller.

Comment: @DavidReed - My problem is - My lightning component is working as we expected like receiving events using lightning empiAPi and updating real time record but rare cases its same functionality not working.. like sometimes working and sometime not working.

Comment: @Ajay I don't have an answer to that based on this comment.

Comment: @DavidReed  I have did some coding for unsubscribing the event, could you review those lines of code please?

Comment: In JsController -  const subscription = component.get('v.subscription')
        empApi.unsubscribe(subscription, $A.getCallback(unsubscribed => {
            component.set('v.subscription', null);
        })); I didn't use handler for unsubcribe in component, just did in controller only. Please suggest me

Comment: @Ajay Please open separate questions for new issues and make sure to include a *complete, reproducible example* so folks can try it out. I don't know the answer to this one, and comment threads are not the right place.